# Get angle between two 2d lines. (With respect to the direction of the lines)

Tags: math, rotation, 2d, line, angle

I want to get the angle between two lines with respect to direction of the line. A normal dot product of the 2 vectors of the lines always returns the lowest angle between the two lines, which is not what I'm looking for.

Example image:
[image: What I am looking for...]

Blue lines: The lines I have
Red lines: indication of the direction
Green lines: failed attempt at a curving line that indicates the direction of the rotation I want.
p0~p3: the x, y coordinates of the points of the lines.
a: The angle I am looking to get.

I want to build a function that gives me the correct rotation, use any programming language you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution to this, but the following works:

Compute the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two vectors.
If the cross product is negative, compute the inner angle (called "alpha") using the dot product, otherwise if the cross product is positive, compute the outer angle as 360°-alpha.

Note that the cross product depends on the order of operands; the above is valid assuming the order as in your drawing.

Comment: Sounds like it could work, though a single calculation would be more elegant if possible. Yes my line order is determined as described in the image.

Comment: If you really want it in one line, you could do

angle = mod(arccos(-sign(c)*d/ ( ||v1||*||v2|| ) ), 360),

where c = cross product, d = dot product and ||.|| the length of the vectors v1 and v2. But I think and if-else clause is more readable.

Comment: Hi @Nibor. Would you be able to show an example of this calculation using python. Sorry but all this calculation is new for me. But I have the same exactly requirement.

ManIkWeet Did you manage to do it? Could you help me?